# Integrate PHPExcel in Zend Framework 2

Tags: zend-framework2, phpexcel

Using composer I have downloaded the PHPExcel class. The directory structure is

```
codeplex 
+-phpexcel  
  +-PHPExcel
```

now I am confuse how to enable PHPExcel class in application.config.php OR should i remove the extra folder structure?

I know it's a basic question but I am just getting fatal error around enabling this.

Comment: Please note this is ZF2 specific question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHPExcel is not a ZF2 module, so you don't need to do anything to enable it. Since you've installed it via. Composer, Composer will have setup the autoloading for you, so you should be able to use the PHPExcel classes in your existing module(s):

```
use PHPExcel;

$excel = new PHPExcel(); 

[etc.]
```

Comment: how will you output the file for save?

Answer (score 0):

PhpExcel class is not a ZF2 module in self and for that you don't be able to enable it through the `application.config.php` file. 
In alternative you can use [MvlabsPHPExcel](https://github.com/mvlabs/MvlabsPHPExcel) module that gives the possibility to use [PHPOffice/PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) library into a ZF2 application.

To add the module through composer simply:

`$ php composer.phar require mvlabs/mvlabs-phpexcel`

After that, you'll be able to add it in your `application.config.php`file.

```
<?php
return [
    'modules' => [
        // ...
        'MvlabsPHPExcel',            
    ],
    // ...
];
```